# PivotTable Grouping multiple colums with qualitative data

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a large table, with for each row 1 to 3 qualitative data in three columns (Same list of possible  values in each column). I would like to export the data into a PivotTable that merges these three columns to show a total count of all occurrences of the specific value.

See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwNbI.png) for more context, and [this screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY48G.png)
for what i would like to achieve.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is much easier using a CountIf formula. Place your distinct Qualitative elements into a column (column F below), and then add a formula for counting how many times each appear in your Qualitative array.

Here's the formula for cell G2:

```
    =COUNTIF($B$1:$D$10,F2)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, after some research I resorted to doing this. Would have prefered it to be in a pivotTable though, to easily sort/filter by department and other variables.
Thanks for your answer!